# perl 5.12 64bit with xampp

Tags: perl, windows-7, xampp

I am using xampp 1.7.4 in Win 7 64bit. Xampp is config with perl 5.10, the nmake doesn't run in 64 bit win 7, so, no mod can be installed.

Is possible to configure xampp with perl 5.12 64bit? Or have any other solution. I am primary using Perl, Php and Mysql on apache.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I looked at XAMPP on Windows (Stackers, edits/improvements welcome). IIRC one only needed to change the registry key for the [ScriptInterpreterSource](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#scriptinterpretersource) directive. You can install a non-crippled distro like [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) (comes with `dmake`) and point the configuration or shebang lines to the location of its perl binary. You can then simply ignore the XAMPP Perl. I do not know what to do to integrate mod_perl2 (no httpd headers/apxs available? please verify).

Remember that XAMPP is designed to give novice users a *development environment* and an initial foothold so that they can get stuff done and a quick first sense of achievement, at the cost of flexibility in the software setup. If you then find yourself restricted by the choices made by the "Apache friends" dev group, you should move off and learn how to set up the toolchain of httpd/perl/mod_perl yourself. This is eventually necessary anyway because you need a hardened *production environment* facing the real Web, which XAMPP is not suitable for.

Comment: As daxim said, using windows platform just for development. Before seeing this reply, I installed uniserver and activestate perl 64bit. Uniserver also has not mod-perl.